# RTL support in sIFR, Cufon, and Typeface.js

Tags: typography, web-fonts

I want to use some font-embedding technology for a website which uses right-to-left language. I don't know which of these alternative ways of font-embedding support right-to-left languages.

If they don't support it yet, do they have plan to add it in future?

Is there any better way to embed fonts for RTL languages?

Comment: Do you know, for a fact, that these technologies do not support RTL languages? At the same time, we cannot speculate on what a developer may or may not do; you will have to ask the developers their intents.

Answer (score 3):

I think using CSS3 `@font-face` rule is a better option. All the technologies you've mentioned are being developed by very few developers and have many drawbacks. They may stop being developed at any time and as I saw their websites, they're mainly donation-driven projects. Therefore, they are highly likely to get out of scope in future.

However `@font-face` rule is authored and supported by [W3C](http://www.w3.org) (the organization behind making web standards) and has been implemented in browsers natively. In other words, while something like sIFR is only a workaround to embed a font-face (a type) in web browsers based on Flash and JavaScript infrastructure, `@font-face` is what Firefox **has**, or Chrome **has**, or IE **has** built-in.

Thus, I strongly recommend that you go after `@font-face` to see if it can solve your problem.

To read more about `@font-face` rule, read [CSS3 Fonts Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule)